# How can I scrape social media sites the same way Google does? Does Google use each site-specific API, or site-nonspecific crawling?

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

How can I scrape social media sites the same way Google does?  Does Google use each site-specific API to extract site contents, or site-nonspecific crawling?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's officially agreement or API they use for that. I believe they had a special agreement with Twitter years ago (when [this came up](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-adds-view-on-twitter-21415.html)), but I'm not sure such a thing exists anymore.

If you see [Facebook's robots.txt](https://facebook.com/robots.txt) you'll notice they have some blockers so I believe Google crawls them like any other site.

That's not to say that the site owners don't have special treatments for Googlebot on their end. If you want to see a page like Googlebot does, use the [Mobile Friendly Testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly).